# sonar not working with maven-2.0.9. is there a workaround for /batch_bootstrap error?

Tags: maven, maven-2, sonarqube

I installed sonar-3.7.2 without issue. I have it working properly with oracle. I can analyze maven-3 projects from a client machine on the same network as the sonarqube server.

The docs says it supports maven-3.x and maven-2.2.x. We are in the process of upgrading projects to maven-3 but many of our projects still use maven-2.0.9. I was hoping that the 2.2.x condition was merely due to what people were testing with and not a real limitation but some newly downloaded poms in my artifactory contain the property maven.min.version set to 2.2.1.

I need a version that will work with maven-2.0.9.
I saw a log from one of my coworkers also trying out sonar and it showed maven-2.0.9 was being used successfully. He is using defaults. I am setting up for production.

The error that I get (cleaned up of course):
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://myhost:myport/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=mygroupid:myartifactid]. Response code: 400

I have tried sonar 3.7.2, 3.6.3 and 3.5.1 and get the same error in each case. In each case
analyzing a maven-3 project works (to prove everything else is ok)

I have tried adding the webcontext /sonar instead of just /.
I have tried setting the Server base url in the sonarqube server even though I have not tested anything yet related to sending emails.

I saw something about corruption in the local .m2 on another thread. Removing it did not help either.

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Best Regards, Gord Cody

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is quite clear : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven

SonarQube supports only Maven 2.2.x and 3.x 
But my question is : What's the problem to upgrade from maven 2.0.9 to 2.2.x?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I did see that comment but I was unable to determine why that new limitation was being imposed. Earlier versions of sonar did work with previous versions of maven.

Comment: We have a lot of projects that still rely on 2.0.9 and we are migrating to maven-3 but things move slowly here as many developers would be immediately affected. We did try upgrading to maven 2.2.x when it was new but there were issues with multiple plugin changes that forced us to revert to 2.0.9. Switching to 2.2.x was not simply download/install/continue working. I wont get approval to upgrade projects to 2.2.1 now. Its redundant.